# I am trying to excerpt a long comment in my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to excerpt a long comment in my wordpress site.

I want to do it in coding.

I have not tried downloading a plugin yet.

I have a comment section on each post, sometimes some customer comments longer. So i want to make things orderly that to only show at least 20 words per comment and hide the other part or put continue reading.

here is my site https://alamngpinoy.000webhostapp.com/

i am new to wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function

comment_excerpt( $comment_ID ) or get_comment_excerpt( $comment_ID )

for this please check reference

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_excerpt

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_excerpt

Comment: Sorry, i am really new to this. Do have a video somehow that can show the steps?